# how to call angular scope function from javascript function inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have angular controller and Javascript function in that function , i am calling angular function. I am getting error: $scope.Name is not a function, $scope.dates is not a function.

```
     function validation() {
            $scope.pageload = true;

            $scope.Name();
            $scope.dates();  
        }

        $scope.Name = function () {
           // do something
        }

        $scope.dates = function () {
          // do something       
        }
```

working fine inside the controller

```
    var MyController = function ($scope, service)
    {


       function validation() {

            $scope.pageload = true;

            $scope.Name();
         $scope.dates();

        }

       $scope.Name = function () {


            // do something
        }

     $scope.dates = function () {

            // do something

    }


});


working:


var MyController = function ($scope, service)
{
 LoginHomeService.getHomeService(function (data) {
                $rootScope.CT1SessionObj = data.CT1SessionObj;

                        validation();



                                    }, function (response) {
                                        alert(response.Message);
                                    });

   function validation() {

        $scope.pageload = true;

        $scope.Name();
     $scope.dates();

    }

   $scope.Name = function () {


        // do something
    }

 $scope.dates = function () {

        // do something




});




Not working:

    var MyController = function ($scope, service)
    {
     LoginHomeService.getHomeService(function (data) {
                    $rootScope.CT1SessionObj = data.CT1SessionObj;

                            validation();


   function validation() {

        $scope.pageload = true;

         $scope.Name();
         $scope.dates();

        }

       $scope.Name = function () {


            // do something
        }

     $scope.dates = function () {

            // do something

    }


   }, function (response) {
    alert(response.Message);
   });


   });
```

Comment: Where is all of this code sitting? Is this all inside a controller or ...?

Comment: call `validation()` from somewhee

Comment: You may want to create a Plunker: https://plnkr.co/

Comment: no inside the  controller calling the service  

inside the service   rcalling the validation  javascript function,In js function calling the angular function.

Comment: inside the controller working ,for some reasons i have put inside the service reponse

Comment: You need to show more context, but my guess is you have scoping issues.

Answer (score 3):

Declare `$scope.Name` and `$scope.dates` on top of `validation()`

Javascript works from top to bottom, so your functions `$scope.Name` and `$scope.Dates` do not exist 'yet'.

Also, try not to use 'Name' as a function. Most of these words are reserved keywords.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.Name = function() {
    // do something
  }

  $scope.dates = function() {
    // do something       
  }

  function validation() {
    $scope.pageload = true;

    $scope.Name();
    $scope.dates();
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/4872/

An even better approach would be the 'John Papa style' : [Y033](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y033)

> Place bindable members at the top of the controller, alphabetized, and not spread through the controller code.
>
> Why?: Placing bindable members at the top makes it easy to read and
>   helps you instantly identify which members of the controller can be
>   bound and used in the View.
>
> Why?: Setting anonymous functions in-line can be easy, but when those
>   functions are more than 1 line of code they can reduce the
>   readability. Defining the functions below the bindable members (the
>   functions will be hoisted) moves the implementation details down,
>   keeps the bindable members up top, and makes it easier to read.

```
/* avoid */
function SessionsController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.gotoSession = function() {
      /* ... */
    };
    vm.refresh = function() {
      /* ... */
    };
    vm.search = function() {
      /* ... */
    };
    vm.sessions = [];
    vm.title = 'Sessions';
}


/* recommended */
function SessionsController() {
    var vm = this;

    vm.gotoSession = gotoSession;
    vm.refresh = refresh;
    vm.search = search;
    vm.sessions = [];
    vm.title = 'Sessions';

    ////////////

    function gotoSession() {
      /* */
    }

    function refresh() {
      /* */
    }

    function search() {
      /* */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Harald Wiesinger mentioned declare called functions prior to calling function.

Comment: If you want to mention someone , use comment instead of answer

Answer (score -1):

Put validation after the scope functions

```
$scope.Name = function () {
   // do something
}

$scope.dates = function () {
  // do something       
}

function validation() {
    $scope.pageload = true;

    $scope.Name();
    $scope.dates();  
}
```